# How to record phone call via DialUp modem

Tags: c#, .net, record, modem, dial-up

I've tried [this program](http://www.concelsys.com/voice_modem_software_call_recorder_logger_apr.htm) and It's compatible with each dial up modems connected to my laptop and I think it's using a windows API or a public API because the other programs I saw were only compatible with serial port modems but It's working with my USB modem

Is there any compatible library in C# to record calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/TAPI-3-in-C-Get-Lines-and-dd143eaf

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-3-0-Application-development-using-C-NET

The Telephony API is right from Windows, so it might be pretty low-level, but should support what you need.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that `There is no connection for this connection ID (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040004 (OLE_E_NOCONNECTION))`

Comment: For this to be diagnosed you'll have to post your code and probably a stack trace.

Comment: Which link? What compiler did you use? And when you debug it, give the stack trace to where the error is generated.

Comment: The first link actually. But I get another error whit the second one. I'm using VS Express 12

Comment: > TapiSample.exe!TapiSample.Form1.button1_Click(object sender = {Text = "Use Line"}, System.EventArgs e = {X = 56 Y = 14 Button = Left}) Line 47 + 0x34 bytes C#

Comment: and the exception is in line `cn = tapi.RegisterCallNotifications(line, true, true, TAPI3Lib.TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO, 2);`

Comment: Isn't there any documentation for this library?

Answer (score 1):

**"I'm getting an error saying that There is no connection for this connection ID (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040004 (OLE_E_NOCONNECTION))"**

Most probably your modem is not full duplex voice modem. 
This error was also happening on my PC as well and was removed by changing Modem